# Either/or assertions unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

In a unittest I want to do something like:

```
result = myFunction()
self.assertFalse(result) OR self.assertRaises(Exception, myFunction)
```

with the idea being that if the implementation of `myFunction` changes to return false instead of raise an exception (or vice-versa), the test will still behave correctly (i.e. indicate a non-positive result).

Is something like this possible?

Comment: If `myFunction()` raises an exception, line 2 ought not run. Is that what you desire? I do find it hard to imagine a function go from returning False to raising an exception a place where a test should be indifferent as those are radically different results. Is it possible to give a case where both would test OK?

Comment: Don't. If `myFunction` returns `False` now, test that is does so. If and when you change it to raise an exception instead, update the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `myFunction()` raises a specific exception:

```
try:
    self.assertFalse(myFunction())
except SpecificException:
    pass
```

In this case if `myFunction()` raises `SpecificException` it would be silently ignored.

In other words, you would see the test failing in two cases: either `myFunction()` raises the exception you are not waiting for, or the result of `myFunction()` call doesn't evaluate to `False`.

---

In case if your function can throw any exception, you can check whether you caught an `AssertionError` in the except block and reraise it, silently ignoring other exceptions:

```
try:
    self.assertFalse(myFunction())
except AssertionError:
    raise
except:
    pass
```

---

Note that this doesn't seem very intuitive and clear to me. In an ideal world, you would need to handle these two situations separately: create a test that would make `myFunction()` result into `False` and another one that would make it raise an exception.

Comment: I've accepted this as it does answer my questions, but the comments are well taken in that I will actually instead change the implementation of the function to behave more uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

You could, but that will make your test weaker. Every other unit test that uses myFunction will have to assume that it could either raise an exception or return False -- or else *that* test may break when the behavior changes.

Making all your other tests accomodate this uncertainty will make all those pieces of code harder to write. And for what purpose? The benefit is dubious.

Instead, make a definite test which uses `assertRaises`. Let the test fail if the implementation changes, and change the test then to `assertFalse`. That change may also cause other tests to fail, **and that is a good thing**. It will force you to review use cases for `myFunction`, and the repercussions for changing the behavior.